# readFileSync returns undefined

Tags: node.js

I have a 2MB html file, and node couldn't read that.

what I've tried:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const file_name = process.argv[2];

let blob = fs.readFileSync(file_name, 'utf8')
console.log(blob)
```

this prints 'undefined' to terminal

I've tried unsynchronous version, too:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const file_name = process.argv[2];

fs.readFile(file_name, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
        return false    
    }
    console.log(data)
});
```

this prints 'undefined', too

when I tried other html files, it worked without any problem.

what can I do? is there any specific string pattern causes that node cannot read file?

Comment: Make sure file_name link the correct file.

Comment: file name is correct. when I try some file name that's not exist, node throws error, which is not the case

Comment: I was having this failure in my test suite, I came to this question and couldn't figure out the answer... turns out, I had mocked `fs` in another test case already, and it was returning `undefined` because the entire function was mocked. D'oh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use full path to the file

For example

```
// Dependencies
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
// Add current path to filename
const file_name = path.join(__dirname, process.argv[2]);

// Check if file exist
fs.exists(file_name, function (file) {
  if (file) {
    // Read file with file_name
    fs.readFile(file_name, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return false;
      }
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
  else{
      console.log("file not found");
      return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks! now it prints something like <Buffer 75 6e 64 65 66 69 6e 65 64>
maybe there's some encoding problem? I'll search more

Comment: Try `console.log(data.toString('utf8'));`

Comment: readFile(file_name, 'utf8') ...-> undefined
readFile(file_name)..............-> <Buffer something
data.toString('utf8')..............-> undefined

now I guess that the file has some unordinary byte that I can't easily convert to utf8. but that's 2MB, so it'll take some time to find...

thanks for your time, I'll split it to some smaller files and continue trying.

by the way, how can I 'accept' your answer?

Comment: Yes, you can. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

instead of using `fs.readFile` you can use `fs.readFileSync('./db/user.json');` inside a `try ... catch` block.

```
const fetchAllUser = () => {

    // if file doesn't exists we have to write try catch
    try {
        // path should be relative to app.js / index.js (entry file)
        let userString = fs.readFileSync('./db/user.json');
        return JSON.parse(userString);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(`No database available`);
        return [];
    }
};
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but seems that it's not the case